# if select changes - disable next or previous select

Tags: jquery, select

I have multiple selects - in pairs. And with each pair, I would like for one of them being disabled if the other is changed.

```
<select name='wf_events[]'>
    <option value=''>--</option>";
    foreach ($ug_array AS $ugrow)
        echo "<option value='".$ugrow["user_group_id"]."'>".$ugrow["user_group_name"]." [".$ugrow["user_group_short"]."]</option>";
    echo "
</select>
or
<select name='wf_events[]'>
    <option value=''>--</option>";
    foreach ($users_array AS $userrow)
        echo "<option value='".$userrow["u_id"]."'>".$userrow["u_realname"]." [".$userrow["u_name"]."]</option>";
    echo "
</select>
```

Any one ? Remember - there can be multiple of these pairs.

EDIT:
Tried this:

```
$('.select_1').change(function(e) {
    if ($('.select_1').val()==1){
        $('.select_2').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else{
        $('.select_2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
$('.select_1').trigger('change');
```

but if there is multiple pairs, all select_2 will be disabled. And that is not the point ;-)
And ID's ... nope.

Perhaps calling a function onchange that disables the next - or previous..

EDIT EDIT:

```
$(".selectoption").on("change", function(event){
    if($(this).val() == "") {
    $(event.target).attr("disabled", false);
    $(event.target).next().attr("disabled", false);
    $(event.target).prev().attr("disabled", false);
    }
    else
    {
    $(event.target).attr("disabled", false);
    $(event.target).next().attr("disabled", true);
    $(event.target).prev().attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, btw not the best solution.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Slico/92w1j5ym/4/)

```
$(".selectoption").on("change", function(event){
   $(event.target).attr("disabled", false);
   $(event.target).next().attr("disabled", true);
   $(event.target).prev().attr("disabled", true);
});
```